# How would you create a layout like this?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager

I would like to create the main menu for my program and I have difficulties with Swing.

How would you code an alignment like this?

[image]

The middle elements would be the options like exit or settings and this window should be able to be resized and its contents should get bigger proportionally.

Answer (score 3):

Single column `GridLayout` with vertical padding declared in the constructor. A grid layout will stretch components to fit the available space.

Add a large `EmptyBorder` to the `JPanel` that contains the 3 buttons, and that's the job done.